# regex to fetch number from json

Tags: regex, irule

How to get the required format text output from json payload using regexp

```
"number" : 4aac4c35-8e3e-4730-8364-381884d6f20f:OP:QUAL:117804471:PON:false
```

what is the expression to get the output like following

```
"number" : 117804471
```

could you please help.

I tried the following; but it didn't work; I am newbie to this.

```
([\"]token[\"][\s]*:[\s]*)?([0-9]{9})
```

Comment: Normally, depending on your environment, you do not parse JSON yourself. There should be some kind of parser to access it via objects and properties or sth.

Comment: What you want is not really clear. Do you want to extract a part of the given output? Where does is come from? Add some explanation and context to help us help you.

Comment: @ChrᴉzsaysreinstateMonica, Got it. but I am trying in my local system, for one usecase. could you please help

Comment: @PJProudhon. I am validating here, https://regex101.com/r/9WgsVb/2

Comment: @Creator: Have you got more examples of what "number" could contain? Is the number always 9 symbols long as you expect in your regex? Is "QUAL" or "PON" always present or not?

Comment: @Pj, Yes, always it will be there

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: @Toto, this is for iRule configuration, for loadbalancing

Comment: A regex matches only consecutive characters. What you want can't be done with a simple match, you have to match 2 distinct substrings and concatenate them progammaticaly.

Comment: iRule just takes the regularExp

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as @PJProudhon says, we are lacking some precisions to help you.

If you just want to extract the number without using some capturing groups, you could go with this regular expression: `(?<=:)\d+(?=:\w+:(?:true|false))`

Quick explanation:

- `(?<=:)` is a positive lookbehind to find the `:` char.
- `\d+` is to get a number of at least 1 decimal or more.
- `(?=:\w+:(?:true|false))` is a positive lookahead to find a `:`, a word, a `:` and then 
  `true` or `false`.

Small test with multiple values here: https://regex101.com/r/1nRnct/2

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but how to get the output/Full match like this "number":"117804471"

Comment: Well, you could remake it yourself by recreating the string or you could simply use the solution that @PJProudhon gave you with a substitution ;-)

Comment: Okay I will try. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Still not very sure of what you exactly want or need, but let's give a try, based on what you wrote here and in your sample.

Receiving some string respecting the following:

- Starting with a double-quote enclosed token.
- Followed by a colon, occasionally surrounded by any number of spacing characters.
- Followed on the right part by a suit of colon separated tokens.
- One of those being composed of numbers only.

Trying to replace that input by only:

- Double-quote enclosed token.
- Followed by a colon, surrounded spaces kept.
- Immediately followed by the number only token.

You could then use the following pattern to get your match: `^(?<token>"[^"]+"\s*:\s*)(?:\d*[^\d:][^:]*:)*(?<number>\d+)(?::[^:]*)*$`.

The following should then be used to replace: `$1$2`.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/2vNpMU/1).

That may be simplified or adapted when knowing additional rules.

Comment: Question is, how can I get "number":"117804471" out of this string "number" : 4aac4c35-8e3e-4730-8364-381884d6f20f:OP:QUAL:117804471:PON:false
using regular expression

Comment: Isn't it the result on regex101?

Comment: I just need regexp, I will try by combining with both answers